# Is it possible to pot a line chart of date vs time in ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am trying to plot a line chart of date vs time using the following code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("lineChart");
data = JSON.parse('JSON string');

var myLineChart = new Chart(canvas, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {parser: 'HH:mm'}
                }],
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {parser: 'YYYY-MM-DD'}
                }],
        },
    }
});
```

Is this possible? Should I convert the `HH:mm` to milliseconds instead?

**UPDATE**

Chrome console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined
    at i.getLabelMoment (Chart.min.js:14)
    at i.getPixelForValue (Chart.min.js:14)
    at i.update (Chart.min.js:11)
    at i.reset (Chart.min.js:12)
    at Chart.min.js:12
    at Object.s.each (Chart.min.js:12)
    at t.Controller.resetElements (Chart.min.js:12)
    at t.Controller.initialize (Chart.min.js:12)
    at new t.Controller (Chart.min.js:12)
    at new t (Chart.min.js:12)
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Did you get an error or something?

Comment: @jordanwillis yes I did. Forgot to include the error message...will update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to use a time scale on both the x and y axis.  Per the [api docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-time-scale)...

> The time scale is used to display times and dates. It can only be placed on the X axis.

If you really need to do this (I'm having trouble thinking​ of a use for this), then you could try using a time scale for your X axis and a category scale for your Y axis.

Just generate string values from your date data for the y value in your dataset object (`{x: new Date(), y: 'May 2017'}`).

Comment: I've been to those Docs so many times and still missed that sentence for going straight to the coding examples. The use case is wanting to plot the time of the day at which a daily event happens. I guess I could convert it to milliseconds and plot it as `int` numbers. ^_^ Thank you!